# ubuntu 20.10 no automount of usb devices

Tags: usb, automount

Suddenly automount of usb devices does not work any more.
I can't link this failure to any update.
Devices show up in lsusb but not in fdisk -l

Help!

Until now I attached a usb device and was asked by a widget wether I wanted to mount it.

No this widget says "no devices available".

I checked some devices on other machines and they were attached as usual.

Comment: Solution: 

You have to remove the usbguard package by:
sudo apt autopurge usbguard
and reboot.